# Excel Pie-in-Pie Chart with Second Pie Sum of 100%

Tags: excel, pie-chart, percentage

I am creating a Pie-in-Pie Chart. [image: Pie-in-Pie]
The image shows what it's looks like right now. I would like that the second pie (right) sums up to 100%.

The underlying data looks as follows (the forth value 28.20% is described in detail by the second pie chart which contains the following values:

[image]

What I tried: Multiply all second pie chart's values by 28.20%. The result is the given pie chart. But the second pie chart doesn't sum up to 100% if I do it that way.

Any recommendation how to tackle this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it can be done. The idea of the pie-in-pie chart is that the slices of the second (smaller) pie are shown as parts of the whole.

Comment: I guess you are right. I ended up changing the numbers by hand.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. Calculate the percentages of the second pie so that they equal 100% then click on the labels within the pie chart to bring up the format menu on the right. Click on 'Label Options' then check the box that says 'Value from Cells'. Then you just need to select the cells with your wanted values and they will be visible on the pie slices.